# Effiecient way to get data from database in foreach

Tags: laravel, optimization, laravel-5.1, query-builder

I am loading data from excel. In foreach I am checking for each record if it does exist in database:

`$recordExists = $this->checkIfExists($record);`

```
function checkIfExists($record) {
    $foundRecord = $this->repository->newQuery()
        ->where(..., $record[...])
        ->where(..., $record[...])
        ...
        ->get();
}
```

When the excel contains up to 1000 values which is relatively small piece of data - the code runs around 2 minutes. I am guessing this is very inefficient way to do it.

I was thinking of passing the array of loaded data to the method `checkIfExists` but then I could not query on the data.

What would be a way to proceed?

Comment: You could get the ids (or another relevant column) of all the records, then cross that information with the ids (or another relevant column) that you want to check and then return the elements that exist and the ones who doesn't.

Comment: @HCK I am not sure if I understand correctly - what you mean is to:
send for example all ids array to the method and then do direct search on that id so I would not make query but I would search in array? If that's what you meant would it be possible to use whereRaw as well ?

Comment: Are you checking only one column or multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel queue if you want to do a lot of work within a very short time. Your code will run on backend. Client can not recognize the process. just show a message to client that this process is under queue. Thats it

You can check the Official Documentation From Below Url
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

Answer (score 0):

If you passes all the data from the database to the function (so no more queries to the database), you can use laravel collections functions to filter.

On of them is `where` => https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where

```
function checkIfExists($record, Collection $fetchedDataFromDatabase) {

    // laravel collectons 'where' function
    $foundRecord = $fetchedDataFromDatabase
        ->where(..., $record[...])
        ->where(..., $record[...]);
}
```

other helpful functions.

- filter
- contains

Comment: Yes that was also what I was thinking of but I wanted to use whereRaw or some query notation